# deleting file (.txt) using php

Tags: php, delete-file

I have a problem deleting a file using php code/language. I tried `unlink("file.txt");` but it doesn’t work for me. I searched the Web but the same result it says `unlink` or `delete("file.text");`

Neither works for me.

I also tried this (I just got it from other sites/forum):

```
$f = fopen("file.txt","w");
fwrite($f, "");
fclose($f);
unlink("file.txt");
```

But it doesn’t work either. Any other idea for this to work?

Comment: What is the privilege on the file ?

Comment: are you sure you/your www-data-user has the permission to delete files?

Comment: Try: @unlink("file.txt");

Comment: enable the warnings and check the error return by unlink

Comment: From the documentation for unlink: *An E_WARNING level error will be generated on failure.* Try turning up your log level and looking at it.

Comment: @PrakashPanchal — Why would **hiding** error messages make it work?

Comment: It just hiding warning not error.

Comment: @PrakashPanchal — And why would hiding the information that tells you what the problem is fix the problem?

Comment: you might want to try with the full path to the file?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work" ? What does it do, and what do you expect? Also, check logs for warnings and errors.

Comment: You have to use the full path of your server to remove file....

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to use the path of your server to delete the image, like below.

```
unlink('/var/www/test/folder/file.txt'); // this is correct way
```